# Using Unity IoC to register and resolve SignalR hubs

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, signalr, ioc-container, signalr-hub

I think I'm missing something very simple and maybe just need a new set of eyes.  I have an ASP.NET MVC application.  In that app, I am using Unity for my IoC to handle dependency injection.  Each of my repositories need to have a database factory injected into it and each database factory needs to have a principal injected into it.  So far, I've been utilizing the PerRequestLifetimeManager to register these.

```
//Repositories

container.RegisterType<ChatMessageRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
           container.RegisterType<SignalRConnectionRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());

//Context
container.RegisterType<IPrincipal, Principal>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IDatabaseFactory, DatabaseFactory>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

Logically, I've tried to register my Hub in the same fashion.

```
container.RegisterType<ChatHub>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

However, whenever I run my app and navigate away from my chat page, I get a "Resolution of the dependency failed" exception and the InnerException tells me "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."  I've also tried using the default (Transient), PerResolve, and ContainerControlled lifetime Unity managers when registering these guys and cannot seem to get resolve my issue.

Could someone just provide me some demo code with how you used Unity in an ASP.NET MVC application to handle dependency injection into your signalr hubs?

Here's where Unity will inject parameters into my SignalR Hub

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ChatMessageRepository _chatMessageRepository;
    private readonly SignalRConnectionRepository _signalRConnectionRepository;
    private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public ChatHub(ChatMessageRepository chatMessageRepository,
        SignalRConnectionRepository signalRConnectionRepository,
        UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _chatMessageRepository = chatMessageRepository;
        _signalRConnectionRepository = signalRConnectionRepository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    } ... }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Do it in 3 steps

First. Create UnityHubActivator class

```
public class UnityHubActivator : IHubActivator
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public UnityHubActivator(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IHub Create(HubDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        return (IHub)_container.Resolve(descriptor.HubType);
    }
}
```

Second. Create Unity container and register your dependency resolver before run Startup class

```
unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
var unityHubActivator = new UnityHubActivator(_unityContainer);
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IHubActivator), () => unityHubActivator);
//register some types in container
WebApp.Start<Startup>(startOptions);
```

Third. Use it in your Hub

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public MyHub(Logger logger)
    {
        logger.Info("hub constructor");
    }
}
```

Note. I do not change anything in my Startup class

Comment: Does the HttpContext change each time a Hub method is called? I am trying to understand whether it makes sense to use PerRequestLifeTimeManager() anymore?

Comment: The second step can be just `container.RegisterInstance<IHubActivator>(new UnityHubActivator(container));`

Answer (score 1):

There's a trick to do that. You will need to do something like this:

```
container.RegisterType< ChatHub >(new InjectionFactory(CreateChatHub));

......
```

and then create a private method CreateChatHub

```
private static object CreateChatHub(IUnityContainer container)
{
    return new ChatHub();
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that my ChatHub needs parameters to be injected in as part of the constructor.  Three of those parameters (ChatRepository, SignalRConnectionRepository, and UnitOfWork) are already registered with Unity but are registered using the PerRequestLifetimeManager.  However, I don't think that a SignalR Hub's lifecycle meshes well with this PerRequestLifetimeManager.  Do I need to register these repos multiple ways?  One way for my MVC controllers and another way for my SignalR Hubs?

Answer (score 0):

1 Create "UnitySignalRDependencyResolver.cs"

```
public class UnitySignalRDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    protected IUnityContainer Container;
    private bool IsDisposed = false;

    public UnitySignalRDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }

        Container = container.CreateChildContainer();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Autofac implementation of the dependency resolver.
    /// </summary>
    public static UnitySignalRDependencyResolver Current
    {
        get { return GlobalHost.DependencyResolver as UnitySignalRDependencyResolver; }
    }


    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (Container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
        {
            return Container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }

        return base.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (Container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
        {
            return Container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }

        return base.GetServices(serviceType);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        if (IsDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            Container.Dispose();
        }

        IsDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

2.Add your resolver to Owin pipeline

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
         // Get container
        IUnityContainer container = UnityConfig.Container;

        // Create resolver
        var resolver = new UnitySignalRDependencyResolver(container);

        // Create SignalR Configuration
        var config = new HubConfiguration
        {
            Resolver = resolver
        };
        // Start SignalR
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.RunSignalR(config);
        });
    }
}
```

3.Inject your dependency in your controller's constructor

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IMyDependency _myDependency;

    public ValuesController(IMyDependency myDependency)
    {
        _myDependency= myDependency;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to replace `if (Container.IsRegistered(serviceType))` with `if (_container.IsRegistered(serviceType) || typeof(IHub).IsAssignableFrom(serviceType))` so there won't be need to create custom hub activator or register all hubs in container